# How to select radio button with vba excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button

I have 6 option buttons (form control). They are used for searching columns on a table below on the same worksheet. I have a basic search bar. I'd like to create a RESET button where it will reset the column filters and select a specific/default option button. These buttons are (Form Control) because the code I use for the search Macro was only working that way.

```
Private Sub cmd_RESET_BASIC_Click()
'PURPOSE: MANUAL FILTER RESET

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=25
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=24
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Option Button 5")).Select

End Sub
```

I tried Recording a macro since I am new.

How can I Select Option Button 5 and make it true and having the others false?

Comment: Probably: ActiveSheet.Optionbuttons("Option Button 5").Value=True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("Option Button 5").Value = True